# Blessings To/For the English team

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> The fans and the coaches had really low expectations of the English team which turned out to be a blessing to them.

Vs

> The fans and the coaches had really low expectations of the English team which turned out to be a blessing for them.

Which one is more correct? Blessings to / for?  And could anybody elaborate on when to use **to** and when use **for** in situations like these ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you're using the word **blessing** literally or figuratively.  In religious contexts, where the meaning is literal, the blessing is **upon** you.  In figurative contexts (e.g. where it simply means "a stroke of good luck" or something like that)  **for** would be appropriate.

If you are speaking of how someone *regards* the thing, either as bad luck or a blessing, you could say "It was a blessing **to** them, but I thought otherwise."
There, **to them** could be paraphrased as "in their opinion" or "as they saw things".

P.S. And when something was truly needed you can use **to** to introduce those  it helped, who regarded it as something they needed:

> The rain was a blessing to the farming community after the two-month drought.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's never clear-cut, "to" indicates an *action, intention*, or *direction*.  You *give* a blessing *to* someone:

> The father gave his blessing **to** the young couple, wishing them many years of married bliss.

"For" indicates *connection* or *location*. Something *is* a blessing *for* someone -- it just *is*, without anyone giving it.

> The longer summer was a blessing **for** the harvest, producing grapes with robust flavor that enhanced the flavor of the wine.

In the context of your sentence, both work, but *blessing for* makes more sense.  If you use *blessing to* then it suggests the fans and coaches are *actively* blessing the English players, which contrasts oddly with their *low expectations*.